# Kvmap bundle problem

Tags: pdftex

I am having a problem with merging map cells using bundle.

I'm trying to get this result:

[image]

But with this code, I'm getting this result:

[image]

Can someone tell me what my mistake is?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{extarticle}                                                                                                                                                                          
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                                                                                                                                                       
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}                                                                                                                                                                                         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}                                                                                                                                                                               

\usepackage{kvmap}                                                                                                                                                                                                
\usepackage{xcolor}                                                                                                                                                                                               

\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      \begin{kvmap}                                                                                                                                                                                               
      \begin{kvmatrix}{C,B,A,E,D}                                                                                                                                                                                 
          {\textcolor{red}{1}} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & {\textcolor{red}{1}} \\                                                                                                                                  
          {\textcolor{red}{1}} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & {\textcolor{red}{1}} \\                                                                                                                                  
          {\textcolor{red}{d}} & d & d & d & d & d & d & {\textcolor{red}{d}} \\                                                                                                                                  
          {\textcolor{red}{1}} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & d & 0 & {\textcolor{red}{1}}                                                                                                                                     
      \end{kvmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                              
      \bundle[invert=true]{0}{0}{7}{3}                                                                                                                                                                           
      \end{kvmap}                                                                                                                                                                                                 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527500/k-map-diagrams-from-rosen/527871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for `kvmap` is that it cannot guess if it should do a horizontal inversion or a vertical inversion. In version 0.3.3 (on its way to CTAN and downloadable from the [project repository artifacts](https://gitlab.com/benfrank/kvmap/-/jobs/487838751/artifacts/browse)), there are new keys to control the behavior.

[image: correct inversion]

With the new version your can code it like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{kvmap}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
      \begin{kvmap}
      \begin{kvmatrix}{C,B,A,E,D}
          {\textcolor{red}{1}} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & {\textcolor{red}{1}} \\
          {\textcolor{red}{1}} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & {\textcolor{red}{1}} \\
          {\textcolor{red}{d}} & d & d & d & d & d & d & {\textcolor{red}{d}} \\
          {\textcolor{red}{1}} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & d & 0 & {\textcolor{red}{1}}
      \end{kvmatrix}
      \bundle[invert=true, vinvert=false, overlapmargins=6pt]{0}{0}{7}{3}
      \end{kvmap}
\end{document}
```